# VHDL How do you ensure that the smallest adder possible will be used?

Tags: vhdl

I don't want to find out post-synthesis that 32-bit adders were used for some operation instead of the much smaller adder that was actually required. For the code below, do I need to break it apart and assign each of the subtraction operations to a variable of the appropriate size to get synthesis to refrain from defaulting to using a 32bit adder, or are more steps required?

```
diff := diff + 
    abs(to_int(reference_window(i)(j)(15 downto 11)) - to_int(search_window(i)(j+k)(15 downto 11))) + 
    abs(to_int(reference_window(i)(j)(10 downto 5)) - to_int(search_window(i)(j+k)(10 downto 5))) + 
    abs(to_int(reference_window(i)(j)(4 downto 0)) - to_int(search_window(i)(j+k)(4 downto 0)));
```

to_int() is defined as follows:

```
function to_int(a : std_logic_vector) return integer is
    begin
        return to_integer(unsigned(a));
    end to_int;
```

I think that this might be a possible answer but it would be better if someone posted an answer that provided specific rules one should follow to make sure your code doesn't accidentally synthesize into a 32 bit adder.

```
red_diff := unsigned(abs(signed(unsigned(reference_window(i)(j)(15 downto 11))) - signed(unsigned(search_window(i)(j+k)(15 downto 11)))));
green_diff := unsigned(abs(signed(unsigned(reference_window(i)(j)(10 downto 5))) - signed(unsigned(search_window(i)(j+k)(10 downto 5)))));
blue_diff := unsigned(abs(signed(unsigned(reference_window(i)(j)(4 downto 0))) - signed(unsigned(search_window(i)(j+k)(4 downto 0)))));
diff := diff + red_diff + green_diff + blue_diff;
```

I have to use the odd-looking signed(unsigned()) conversion because abs() doesn't accept abs(unsigned(a) - unsigned(b))

Comment: This question is too broad, please demonstrate an actual problem, identifying a particular synthesis tool and provide a [mcve]. VHDL integers have no bits, just ranges. Modern synthesis tools pay attention to ranges (including through type conversion or conversion functions (to_integer here) translating integers to binary values for mapping to logic, the operators well known.

Comment: Then you shouldn't use type `integer` for additions. In most tools this type has 32 bit. You should use type `signed`or `unsigned` and specify the number of bits needed in your calculation. You should also reconsider the usage of a variable for `diff` because you might need to save your result in a register to keep your critical path short.